# MySql Selection and SUM issues

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, where-clause, division

Morning all,

I have a sporting results table that I'm having a couple of issues with, which I'm sure are simple, but I can't seem to get my head around why they aren't working.

a) Selecting just the 2014 season.

For a) I assumed that it should just be a WHERE Season = '2014', but it throws up: `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in`. I have also tried = 2014 as the table is an int, but get the same.

Any help greatly appreciated, before I pull all of my hair out! :)

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT team
     , COUNT(*)  played
     , SUM(win)  wins
     , SUM(loss) lost
     , SUM(win)/count(*) pctWon1
     , SUM(draw) draws
     , SUM(SelfScore) ptsfor
     , SUM(OpponentScore) ptsagainst
     , SUM(SelfScore) - SUM(OpponentScore) goal_diff
     , SUM((win*2 + draw)- loss) score
     , SUM(win*2 + draw)/count(*) pctWon

FROM (
      SELECT team
     , SelfScore
     , OpponentScore
     , SelfScore > OpponentScore win
     , SelfScore < OpponentScore loss
     , SelfScore = OpponentScore draw
      FROM (
        SELECT HomeTeam team, HomeScore SelfScore, AwayScore OpponentScore
        FROM Game
        union all select AwayTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore
        FROM Game
       ) a
) b
WHERE Season = '2014'
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY pctWon DESC, score DESC, ptsagainst DESC;
        ");
```

Comment: Can you paste this query in your mysql client and share the error?

Comment: The error for the where is in the initial question. And the maths but im not sure where to start haha

Comment: No, that's PHP's error for an invalid query. I'm asking about **MySQL**'s error.

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'Season' in 'where clause'` But I'm doing the same for all of the other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying a `where` clause to the outer query (`b`), where there is no such column `Season` there. You should move it to the inner query:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT team
     , COUNT(*)  played
     , SUM(win)  wins
     , SUM(loss) lost
     , SUM(win)/count(*) pctWon1
     , SUM(draw) draws
     , SUM(SelfScore) ptsfor
     , SUM(OpponentScore) ptsagainst
     , SUM(SelfScore) - SUM(OpponentScore) goal_diff
     , SUM((win*2 + draw)- loss) score
     , SUM(win*2 + draw)/count(*) pctWon

FROM (
      SELECT team
     , SelfScore
     , OpponentScore
     , SelfScore > OpponentScore win
     , SelfScore < OpponentScore loss
     , SelfScore = OpponentScore draw
      FROM (
        SELECT HomeTeam team, HomeScore SelfScore, AwayScore OpponentScore
        FROM Game
        WHERE Season = '2014'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT AwayTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore
        FROM Game
        WHERE Season = '2014'
       ) a
) b
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY pctWon DESC, score DESC, ptsagainst DESC;
");
```

Comment: Awesome, that's the answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two levels of subqueries for what you are doing.  (MySQL actually materializes the subqueries which adds a performance overhead.).  But, if you do, you should pull all the fields you want out of them.

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT team, COUNT(*)  played, SUM(IsWin) as wins, SUM(IsLoss) as losses,
       SUM(IsWin)/count(*) as pctWon1,
       SUM(Draw) as draws,
       SUM(SelfScore) as ptsfor, SUM(OpponentScore) as ptsagainst,
       SUM(SelfScore) - SUM(OpponentScore) as goal_diff,
       SUM((IsWin*2 + IsDraw) - IsLoss) as score,
       SUM(IsWin*2 + IsDraw) / count(*) pctWon
FROM (SELECT season, HomeTeam as team, HomeScore as SelfScore, AwayScore as OpponentScore,
             (HomeScore > AwayScore) as IsWin,
             (HomeScore < AwayScore) as IsLoss,
             (HomeScore = AwayScore) as IsDraw
      FROM Game
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Season, AwayTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore,
             (AwayScore > HomeScore) as IsWin,
             (AwayScore < HomeScore) as IsLoss,
             (AwayScore = HomeScore) as IsDraw
      FROM Game
     ) t
WHERE Season = 2014
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY pctWon DESC, score DESC, ptsagainst DESC;
```

I'm not thrilled with repeated the definitions of the flags three times.  And, in most databases, I would prefer to have the logic once in a subquery.  MySQL, though, as an actual performance penalty, so it is best to be avoided.

A small suggestion:  use `as` when defining column aliases.  This will help you find errors when you have a missing comma.

Comment: That's picking up a syntax `#1054 - Unknown column 'SelfScore' in 'field list' `